# Automatically insert pagination

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I have many posts and don't want to go through them all to paginate them with shortcode.

I am looking for a plugin that I can get to insert pagination after a certain amount of images in a post.

I can't seem to find one and there must be a way to do this surely??

Most plugins I have found either use shortcode, put a button in wordpress post editor or use paragraphs. I want to splits posts based on Img

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two way to solve this problem. One is with code (which I would recommend for you) and second way without code and with plugin only (not recommended because you will loose your chance of learning some code).

> First way

You need to create a new php file in you theme folder in which you will write below code to show list of posts. I gave explanation of code in comments. See whole code and read comments with line of code so that you can understand how this code works.

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Posts
*/
get_header();
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$args = array('post_type' => 'post',    // Specifying post type
    'posts_per_page' => 10,             // Number of posts per page to show
    'paged' => $paged                   //for pagination
    );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
//content start from here
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();     //while loop to start writing content of pags
?>
    <li style="list-style:none;">
    <? // it will print the title of the post?>
    <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><font style="color:#666666;"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h3>  
    <?php 
    /*****     Thumbnail     ******/
    the_post_thumbnail(
array(120, 90), 
array(

    'class' => 'thumbnail',
    'alt' => 'post thumbnail',
    'title' => 'Notice'
)
);
/*******     Thumbnail Ends   ********/
// the_content function will print discription of the post
the_content(__('Continue Reading'));?></font>          
    </li><hr />
<?php 
endwhile;
//Shortcode of plugin with custom variable
wp_pagenavi( array( 'query' => $loop ) );
get_footer();?>
```

when you will create file for this code then your file got ready with code then just create new page (empty/blank) in wordpress dashboard. In the edit section of that page on right hand side there is a option with the name `Template` which is by default selected as `default` option. You need to select `post` option from there. Post name is appear because you just created post template and given it the name `post` (In the second line of code). To know more how to create page template just read [this article](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/)

Download [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-pagenavi/) for pagination. I have put the shortcode for plugin in second last line of code. Just download this plugin and change the setting of plugin from plugin's admin panel as per your need.
And feel free to ask if you have any doubt regarding my answer.

> Second way

It would be good if you go to the first way which I have shown above with code. It will improve your coding knowledge as well. But if you are in big hurry and want shortcut (which is not preffered) then instead of using above code or above mentioned plugin you just can use only one plugin for that. [This plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/content-views-query-and-display-post-page/) meght solve your issue without code.

Answer (score 0):

You need something like it

[Wordpress pagination](http://callmenick.com/post/custom-wordpress-loop-with-pagination)

Comment: Can I ask why people down vote this? It is a question and I was told this is the place to ask it.

Comment: if you write some code and there is some bug or mistake you can ask it in stackoverflow , but it`s not right to ask such questions without any code.

Comment: I am not an expert at this so I apologise for not writing any code here.
Do you know somewhere I can ask this question?